# Where to ask questions about the history of the design of Internet Protocol (IP)?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, asking-questions, scope

Seeing [Moon base internet functionality](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/188405/40033) in Worldbuilding reminded me of how I began an old Space SE question [Are there discussions or plans for extending the internet into space beyond Earth?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/15539/12102)

> Many years ago I remember reading about the upcoming implementation of the [internet protocol IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address) - which is now in place. In that article it mentioned that there was some discussion about space - I mean *outer space*, not namespace. At the time, it seemed that the author was not just speculating, but that they were actually referring to some plans or at least calculations.

I still want to see if I can track this down and find out if I'm mis-remembering, or mis-understood, or if the development of IPv6 or earlier explicitly took interplanetary distances or needing enough IP addresses for the whole solar system into consideration, or if it was just some creative journalism.

**Question:** Where is the best site to ask such a question?

Comment: Perhaps skeptics?

Comment: @Luuklag I'm not sure if "I might or might not have read once and don't remember where..." questions work there.

Comment: @rene I did! I'd left a link to this question in their chat room, as well as in HSM's. That does seem likely to be the best place; it's a wonderful community and I always get great answers there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that can fit on [Retrocomputing](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> Questions are most welcomed on
> ...
>
> - computing history and persons with a historic relation to computing.

They have a special tag for it as well to go in such questions: [history](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history).

Comment: done! [When IPv6 was designed were there any specific considerations for other planets?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/16623/7118) thanks :-)

Comment: Good call, apparently they liked it :-)